# awk: extract 2 timestamp columns and compare the difference

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a comma separated files with 100s of clumns and i filter the result based on column values with following command.

```
find . | xargs zgrep -i , |  awk '{ FS = "," };{ if (( $3 == "8") && ($14=="1") ) {print $10""$8}}'
```

As part of result column number 10 ad 8 returns following result. These are basically timestamp till milliseconds. yyyymmddhhmmssmmm (+0900 is JST and always remain same, mmm means 3 digits miliseconds)

```
20200428030351464+0900 -> column 10
20200428030351329+0900 -> column 8
```

Now, is there any way to print the difference in same row ? almost all the cases difference will be in seconds and milliseconds it wont be in minutes. (In case if this can simplify.

Comment: If the difference will always be less than 60 seconds you can just take the ssmmm part of the two values and substract them. If the result is negative then add 60000.

Comment: Yes,I am just learning awk, i am not ale to figure how to sub string milliseconds part and seconds part and put it together.

Comment: GNU awk has a [mktime](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) function that can turn a string similar to what you have (it's not too hard to reformat your time stamp into what it expects) into seconds-since-1970.  It doesn't handle time zones; it either uses the local time zone or UTC.

Comment: This date format looks like generated based on +%Y%m%d%H%M%S%3N%z , Is there any way to convert this to epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code should look like this

```
find . | xargs zgrep -i , |
   awk 'BEGIN { FS="," }
        $3 == 8 && $14 == 1 {
            f10=substr($10,13,5);
            f8=substr($8,13,5);
            diff=f10-f8;
            if (diff < 0) { diff+=60000 }
            print diff
}'
```

to print the difference in milliseconds, but this is untested as I don't have your data files.

Comment: This gives me some idea as how to proceed. Will work based on this